# jQuery Datepicker clickoutside detection

Tags: jquery, datepicker, click, detection

I have a problem when trying to detect a click outside of a datepicker : I have an input (datepicker). When clicking, the calendar opens. Then I would like to detect when someone click outside the calendar. I use this code :

```
$(document).click(function (e) {

    //click outside detection
    var container = $("#ui-datepicker-div,#datepicker");

    if (!container.is(e.target) // if the target of the click isn't the container...
        && container.has(e.target).length === 0) // ... nor a descendant of the container
    {
        alert("out");
    }
});
```

That works well but there is a problem when I click on the **next** and **prev** button : it trigger the clickoutside event.

http://jsfiddle.net/Fa8Xx/3086/

**My question : How to NOT trigger the outside event when changing month on calendar (click on Prev and Next button...) ?**

Regards.

Comment: Clicking outside the datepicker dismisses it by default, why do you need to detect this?

Comment: @user1592596 If you are just trying to detect the close for validation reason then why not use the datepicker API onClose event? See http://jsfiddle.net/zwp08unb/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use this,

```
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();

$(document).click(function (e) {

    //Clic hors de la ligne ou du calendrier ou du bouton valider dans la derniere colonne
    var container = $("#ui-datepicker-div,#datepicker");

    if (!($(e.target).is($('#ui-datepicker-div,#datepicker')) || $(e.target).has($('#ui-datepicker-div,#datepicker')).length === 0)) 
    {
        alert("out");
    }
});
```